# how to use useEffect and useCallback, so the screen don't call the function before button clicks

Tags: react-native, use-effect, usecallback

I'm learning useEffect and useCallBack hooks. What I'm trying to do is add a function in the useCallBack, and make sure that the screen will not call this function until I click on a button. Here is my sample code below. Currently, it calls the function inside useEffect before I click on the button. My goal is to click on the button then trigger the useEffect function with useCallBack function. Still new to this, thanks for helping out.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import {Button, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';

const submitHandler = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('the inputs tracking');
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Should not be work until submitHandler button is clicked');
  }, [submitHandler]);

return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Click me" onPress={submitHandler}></Button>
    </View>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you wouldn't need to call `submitHandler` from useEffect - just delete the useEffect block and perform all the logic in `submitHandler`.

You're seeing the useEffect run because all useEffects will run on the first render.

*If* the useEffect is somehow necessary, you would need an additional state to track if the button was clicked.

```
const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);

const submitHandler = useCallback(() => {
  console.log('the inputs tracking');
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (clickCount > 0) {
    submitHandler();
  }
}, [clickCount, submitHandler]);

return (
  <View>
    <Button title="Click me" onPress={() => setClickCount((x) => x++)}></Button>
  </View>
);
```

The onPress callback increments the count, which will trigger the useEffect and call submitHandler. Although, I think this is unnecessary and a single useCallback provided to onPress is the right way to go.

Additional comment about your code:

Adding `submitHandler` in useEffect dependency array does not mean the effect will run when `submitHandler` is called. The useEffect will run whenever `submitHandler` changes (it's object reference) and since its dependency array is empty it will never change. This means the useEffect will only fire on the first render.